# Failed to activate mongodb server

Tags: mongodb, 23.10

I use Ubuntu 23.10. I can't start mongodb server. Mongo server is currently version 7.0.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB provides 2 ways to start the service on Ubuntu according to the official documentation. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

**Method 1**

Using systemd(systemctl)

1. Start MongoDB.

   `sudo systemctl start mongod`
2. Verify that MongoDB has started successfully

   `sudo systemctl status mongod`

**Method 2**
Using System V Init (service)

1. Start MongoDB.

   `sudo service mongod start`
2. Verify that MongoDB has started successfully

   `sudo service mongod status`

Method 2 worked for me after I got an "inactive" status on Ubuntu 23.10 when trying to start mongodb.

Hope this helps.